# Issues in Codeigniter PDF

Tags: php, codeigniter

I the below codeigniter code i am working on pdf file when i execute it hello world is only displaying but not the tables pls help me to solve the issue.I have placed the controller below.I download from this site   http://www.christophermonnat.com/2008/08/generating-pdf-files-using-codeigniter/

Controller:

```
<?php

class Tutorial extends controller
{

    function Tutorial()
    {
        parent::Controller();

        $this->load->helper('url');
    }


    function index() 
    {   
        $this->hello_world();
    }


    function hello_world()
    {
        $this->load->library('cezpdf');

        $this->cezpdf->ezText('Hello World', 12, array('justification' => 'center'));
        $this->cezpdf->ezSetDy(-10);

        $content = 'The quick, brown fox jumps over a lazy dog. DJs flock by when MTV ax quiz prog.
                    Junk MTV quiz graced by fox whelps. Bawds jog, flick quartz, vex nymphs.';

        $this->cezpdf->ezText($content, 10);

        $this->cezpdf->ezStream();
    }


    function tables()
    {
        $this->load->library('cezpdf');

        $db_data[] = array('name' => 'Jon Doe', 'phone' => '111-222-3333', 'email' => 'jdoe@someplace.com');
        $db_data[] = array('name' => 'Jane Doe', 'phone' => '222-333-4444', 'email' => 'jane.doe@something.com');
        $db_data[] = array('name' => 'Jon Smith', 'phone' => '333-444-5555', 'email' => 'jsmith@someplacepsecial.com');

        $col_names = array(
            'name' => 'Name',
            'phone' => 'Phone Number',
            'email' => 'E-mail Address'
        );

        $this->cezpdf->ezTable($table_data, $col_names, 'Contact List', array('width'=>550));
        $this->cezpdf->ezStream();
    }


    function headers()
    {
        $this->load->library('cezpdf');
        $this->load->helper('pdf');

        prep_pdf(); // creates the footer for the document we are creating.

        $db_data[] = array('name' => 'Jon Doe', 'phone' => '111-222-3333', 'email' => 'jdoe@someplace.com');
        $db_data[] = array('name' => 'Jane Doe', 'phone' => '222-333-4444', 'email' => 'jane.doe@something.com');
        $db_data[] = array('name' => 'Jon Smith', 'phone' => '333-444-5555', 'email' => 'jsmith@someplacepsecial.com');

        $col_names = array(
            'name' => 'Name',
            'phone' => 'Phone Number',
            'email' => 'E-mail Address'
        );

        $this->cezpdf->ezTable($db_data, $col_names, 'Contact List', array('width'=>550));
        $this->cezpdf->ezStream();
    }

}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try mPdf. Turn css-styled html directly into pdf. On CI you can load parametrized view to mPdf and generate the document. If you're not wheeling on a working project you can do it.

Answer (score -1):

You can use mPDF for generating PDF in Codeigniter.

You can create a controller class and then create function in it. And then do something as bellow code -

```
public function mypdf() { 
    $this->load->library('pdf'); 
    $pdf = $this->pdf->load(); 
    $html=$this->load->view('welcome_message',null,true); 
    $pdf->WriteHTML($html); 
    // write the HTML into the PDF 
    $output = 'itemreport' . date('Y_m_d_H_i_s') . '_.pdf'; 
    $pdf->Output("$output", 'I'); 
}
```

For more detail you can use mPDF for codeigniter. Tutorial [here](http://advancetechtutorial.com/pdf-generate-in-codeigniter-using-mpdf/).

OR

You can try to use DOMPDF for codeigniter. Tutorial [here](https://advancetechtutorial.blogspot.com/2015/09/pdf-generate-in-codeigniter-using-dompdf.html).